# Magento 2.1: how to create category Attribute programmatically?

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

The custom extension in which I am working is working correctly till 2.0.7, but not in 2.1. So my question is, how to create category attribute programmatically?

Below code was working in 2.0.7, but it is not working in 2.1.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'customattribute',
   [
     'group' => 'Custom Group',
                 'type' => 'varchar',
                 'label' => 'Custom Group',
                 'input' => 'textarea',
     'source' => '',
                 'required' => false,
                 'sort_order' => 49,
                 'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
     'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                 'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                 'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                 'is_filterable_in_grid' => true
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento2.1, all attribute load via UI_Component. So you need to assign as a form element following way:

Create **Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="display_settings">
        <field name="customattribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customattribute</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Group</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[Go here for more information](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working. Just have one query, when I applied this code , enable category, include in menu and caetgory name, shows  below (at last) instead of upper area, I hope you are getting me.