# Add category attribute to custom attribute group

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, magento-2.1, install-script

I try to create a category attribute in a Magento 2 install script (or how do we call these now?)

In Magento 1, I could specify anything as `group` and the group would be created. In Magento 2 this seems not to be the case anymore, so I created the group explicitly first:

```
$eavSetup->addAttributeGroup(
    Category::ENTITY,
    $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Category::ENTITY),
    'My group name',
    99
);
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    Category::ENTITY,
    'my_attribute_code',
    [
        'type'              => 'int',
        'input'             => 'select',
        'source'            => Boolean::class,
        'label'             => 'My attribute',
        'group'             => 'My group name',
        'visible'           => 1,
    ]
);
```

The attribute and attribute group is created in the database (`eav_attribute` and `eav_attribute_group`, as well as the relation in `eav_entity_attribute`) but I still do not see the attribute in the backend. What am I missing?

Comment: For M2.1 you need to create UI_Component field for display. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127709/magento-2-1-how-to-create-category-attrbute-programmatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @SohelRana I found out that you now have to write a bunch of additional XML to make anything appear in the category form. Since the answer linked above does not explain how to add a new group, I'll share my result (for one boolean attribute) here:

#### view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="my_group_name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">My group name</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">99</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="my_attribute_code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Attribute</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[STORE VIEW]</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The `argument` element within `fieldset` is necessary to define the properties of the new group. Anything related to attribute group and the admin forms in the database, i.e. from the install script seems to be ignored.