# Create multiselect with source model in UI component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category-attribute, uicomponent, source-model

Since Magento 2.1 you have to define a UI component for custom category attributes (See [Magento 2.1: how to create category attrbute programmatically?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127709/magento-2-1-how-to-create-category-attrbute-programmatically))

I have one multiselect attribute with a custom source model and cannot get it to work. I took `available_sort_by` as an example and managed to show the attribute with a multiselect input but it has no options, i.e. it is not using my source model.

This is the relevant part of `category_form.xml`:

```
    <field name="solr_remove_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-default</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Remove Filters</item>
                <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">#</item>
                    <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Hold the CTRL key to select multiple filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[STORE VIEW]</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

The attribute `solr_remove_filters` has been added with the following install script:

```
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Category::ENTITY,
        'solr_remove_filters',
        [
            'type'              => 'text',
            'input'             => 'multiselect',
            'source'            => FilterableProductAttributeSource::class,
            'backend'           => FilterableProductAttributeBackend::class,
            'label'             => 'Remove Filters',
            'note'              => 'Hold the CTRL key to select multiple filters',
            'required'          => 0,
            'user_defined'      => 0,
            'group'             => 'Solr',
            'global'            => 0,
            'visible'           => 1,
        ]
    );
```

I have set a debug breakpoint in `FilterableProductAttributeSource::getAllOptions()` and see that it is executed and returns an array in the form

```
[
    ['value' => 'value1', 'label' => 'label1'],
    ['value' => 'value2', 'label' => 'label2'],
    ['value' => 'value3', 'label' => 'label3'],
]
```

which confirms that the source model is instantiated and works.

**What do I need to do to populate the UI component with these values?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it, thanks to [GitHub issue #5438](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5438). The source model has to be specified in `category_form.xml` as well:

```
    <field name="solr_remove_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">

            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">IntegerNet\Solr\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\FilterableProductAttribute</item>

            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                ...
```

Just don't ask me why it works without that for `available_sort_by` and why all this redundancy is necessary...

Comment: Hi, i dont understand how 'available_sort_by ' work, please help :)
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238037/magento-2-2-5-explain-about-how-the-multi-select-available-sort-by-get-data

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider source model to display options because you have custom source model if you wants to you can use array backend for source model t display options in admin for category multi select attribute. Your code works because you are telling ui_component that you are going to use following options for you multi select attribute.